# Wordpress HTML code tag not responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

How do I control the width or responsive width of the CODE tag in a Wordpress post?

Under the comments section on this post, the text, "You may use these HTML tags and attributes:" and the code elements after it, doesn't fit the width of the container of this responsive website design.

This line of code examples simply extends out past the container it's in. Here's the post I'm working on:

http://www.flippinlaw.com/what-is-sound-financial-advice.html

I've noticed the issue in 3 different browsers and it seems to be a bootstrap related style. Any help is appreciated greatly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove `white-space: nowrap;` from `code` on bootstrap.css line #983

- It is safe to disable your `code { display: block; }` too

Comment: This way works but it's not a best practice (when your change is long forgotten and your bootstrap.css file gets updated, your change will be overwritten). It's helpful to create your own styles.css file with the
 `code { display: block; white-space: normal; }`. Then set it to load after your bootstrap.css. This simple change makes it a very nice solution for overriding bootstrap.css style properties.

Answer (score 0):

Adding display:block to the code tag looks to work for me

```
code {
    display: block;
}
```

Add it to your style.css file

*edit*
Note that will change it for every code tag on the site, so in case you don't want to do that you can either add it inline to that particular code tag (which isn't really the best idea):

```
<code style="display:block;"></code>
```

Or create a class for it:

```
code.code-block {
    display: block;
}
<code class="code-block"></code>
```

Comment: And maybe also add `overflow-x:scroll;`

Comment: This worked for the apparent container but the tags and attributes are still extending out past the white area. See updated post.

The overflow-x:scroll works but it would be much nicer if we didn't have to display a scrollbar. The hidden attributes works too, but if we could wrap it, this would be best.